# Twilio php api sms service works fine on localhost xampp windows but on live IIS server does not work it returns 500 error code

Tags: php, sms, twilio-php

```
 <?php
       class SmsSenderManager{
            function sendSms($from,$to,$accountId,$token,$msg){
                   $strFromNumber = $from;
                   $strToNumber = $to;
                   $strMsg = $msg; 
                   $result = new stdClass();
                   require_once ("Services/Twilio.php");
                   $AccountSid = $accountId;
                   $AuthToken = $token;
                   $objConnection = new Services_Twilio($AccountSid, $AuthToken);
                   $bSuccess =                                                                                         $objConnection->account->sms_messages->create(
                           $strFromNumber,
                           $strToNumber,
                           $strMsg
                          );     
                  $result->content = $strMsg;
                  $result->success = true;
                  return $result;
                        }
                                                }
      ?>
```

above code sends SMS perfect but does not work on a live project when deployed on IIS server on windows server. I have seen few posts relevant to this problem but most have suggested to allow curl on the server. If so please tell how to enable curl on IIS server

Comment: Google "enable curl IIS"

Comment: while you are gaagling, why not take the time to put in a valid code segment here ?  This one certainly not 'working' on localhost.

Comment: actually twillio php sms api contains lots of files.Documentation can be seen upon https://github.com/twilio/twilio-php

Comment: Resolved! actually the problem was in SSL certificate over IIS server. just open TinyHttp.php in twilio lib:
add CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE, at $opts array

Answer (score 0):

Problem was in SSL certificate over IIS server. just open TinyHttp.php in twilio lib: add `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => FALSE`, at `$opts` array

Comment: from where i get TinyHttp.php file? i have searched from `vendor` folder but i did not get it.